# Deleting all zipfiles in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to delete all the zipfiles under /ABC/DEF. The following of piece of code is not working. What can be the problem?

```
Dir.chdir "/ABC/DEF"

files = Dir.glob("*.zip")

files.each {|i| puts i
            File.delete("#{i}")}
```

Comment: When posting issues saying things like "is not working" isn't sufficient; it's better to post precisely what happened, and any diagnostic steps you've already taken to understand what happened. This should work as-is; I cannot make this break if (a) the directory exists and (b) I have delete rights. Unrelated, but interpolating a string where the string is only another string seems pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Use full path in pattern:

```
files = Dir.glob("/ABC/DEF/*.zip")
```

Comment: No error messages. I tried to add `puts files` but it did not even go till there. I added `begin rescue` but that did not print any error messages either.